# Unable to access SQL Server from SSMS 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm unable to access the server after I installed [Visual Studio Isolated Shell](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/). No matter how I try to access the server, the result will always be the same (image below). How can I access it back without reinstalling it or removing the shell?

[image: Image1.1]

Comment: Go to Services, find the row for SQL Server (your-instance-name), make sure the status = running

Comment: While we're at it, I'm about to explain a few. My intention with this is to know the possibility of modifying the windows theme of SQL Server Express Edition 2014 through isolated VS shell in 2010. Yes, I know that I need to change the color of the tooltip of windows environment. I'm trying to do it through VSTheme 2010 extension. However, I'm unable to install VSTheme extension through VS2010 Ultimate Edition though because of its manifest. My question are: Does the express edition support the extension, Have the manifest been changed through time? and how can i force install the extension?

Comment: @DatNguyen all clear, its still running

Comment: Also another add. If I install it without removing the isolated shell, the setup won't be able to access the directory somewhere in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.x\Extensions\ ..
therefore it won't able to install the rest.

Comment: Make sure you are entering the correct instance name or try with cname if one is created

Comment: I'll give this question a few days until I reinstall this on my own, since I have to do something with it –

Comment: @KASQLDBA the instance is correct, it's the instance that I've been using prior to this experiment, and for "cname" I'll see what I can do with it

Comment: See if this helps - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25132/visual-studio-2017-install-breaks-sql-server-manag.html

Comment: Use a port number explicitly in your connection string or make sure that SQL Server Browser is running

Comment: @KASQLDBA I'm unsure if I'm able to do that since the error log that the guy has is different than mine, but thanks anyway